# Android: Fill Listview the correct way? especially updating

Tags: java, android, database, listview, cursor

I'm working on an APP containing quite a few listviews. What is the correct way to fill a listview? I would especially need it to be updated whenever I did an update or delete an entry. I am using a custom adapter extending the cursoradapter. I know about the following way: creating the Adapter and use setAdapter on the view. Then, one would need the onDataSetChanged of the adapter.

Should i implement it with an cursorloader? Not blocking the Main thread seem quite useful to me. But does this recognize a changed database by itself?

And: is this THE way to attach an Adapter to a listview (lets expand: to an adapterview).

I hope you know what I mean :-).

Cheers!

PS: Thanks to the whole stackoverflow community by having answered SO many questions concerning any type of programming!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to populate a `ListView`.  For your case, if you want it to be handling stuff not in the Main UI thread, use a combination of [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) and [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  This will keep it in the background, and auto-update whenever entries are changed.  [Here](http://appfulcrum.com/2011/09/21/listview-example-5-using-sqlite-database/) is a tutorial using the two together that should get you on your way.